# Magit show status on selected directory

Tags: magit

I have a git repo and I have changes in different directories.

```
user@box:~/myrepo$ git st
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   emacs/basic.el
    modified:   emacs/elisp.el
    modified:   tips/emacs-tips.org
    modified:   tips/linux-tips.org

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    emacs/wip.el
    tips/sqlite.org

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Using command line I can select to show my changes on a **selected directory**.
For example:

```
user@box:~/myrepo$ git st emacs/
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   emacs/basic.el
    modified:   emacs/elisp.el

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    emacs/wip.el

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How can I do that in magit, if possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the status buffer diffs to a directory.  Starting from
the status buffer, try typing <kbd>D=f</kbd>, entering "emacs/", and
then <kbd>g</kbd>.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, even though the interface is a bit confusing. `D` stands for `Change diffs` and `=f` for `Limit to files`. I guess I should read magit's manual, to see if it makes more sense. Anyway, thanks!