# Limit magit to showing status of 1 directory

Tags: magit

I'm working on a large repo with many folders, and showing the status is slow (just plain git takes a long time).

I am really only interested in one directory, how can I constrain magit to only seek the status of one directory so it will be fast.

I am specifically not looking to filter directories after the status is displayed (for an answer to that question see here: [Magit show status on selected directory](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36598/magit-show-status-on-selected-directory))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same request (I actually opened the issue that added this feature [here](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3376)), but was not satisfied with the requirement to add a new file every time I wanted to limit the magit status, so I created `magit-status-current-dir` to open magit in the current directory.

```
  (defun magit-status-in-dir (dir)
"limit magit status to directory"
(interactive "D")
(require 'magit)
(let* ((root (vc-git-root dir))
       (dir (list (file-relative-name dir root)))
       (magit-status-mode-hook (cons (lambda () (setq-local magit-diff-section-file-args dir))
                                     magit-status-mode-hook)))
  (magit-status-internal root)))

(defun magit-status-current-dir ()
  "run magit in current dir"
  (interactive)
  (magit-status-in-dir default-directory))

(defun magit-clear-diff-args-if-not-dir-local ()
  (unless (assq 'magit-diff-section-file-args dir-local-variables-alist)
    (setq-local magit-diff-section-file-args nil)))

(advice-add 'magit-status :around
            (defun magit-remove-diff-args (fn &rest args)
              (let ((magit-status-mode-hook (cons 'magit-clear-diff-args-if-not-dir-local
                                                  magit-status-mode-hook)))
                (apply fn args))))
```

Comment: Ivan's answer is helpful, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: this is a nice answer. Just beware that it sets vc-git-root and this could have unexpected consequences.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [sources](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/78114e6425d5e7d6eaa7712c845f28694aa7faeb/lisp/magit-diff.el#L2359), the directory filters not only affect UI, they are actually passed into `git diff` commands.

To avoid setting filters manually every time, according to [author](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3376#issuecomment-368273740) you can add a snippet to `~/path/to/repo/.dir-locals.el`:

```lisp
((magit-status-mode
  (magit-diff-section-file-args . ("lisp/"))))
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I will try it.